# Centos install in Xen problems

Tags: xen, centos5, centos6

I'm running ubuntu 12.04.1, and I want to install CentOS 5 or 6 using network installation via http.  Using xen images from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.7/os/x86_64/images/xen/

my config:

```
kernel = "/home/virt/centos/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/home/virt/centos/initrd.img"
name = "centos"
memory = "768"
disk = [ 'file:/home/virt/centos/centos6.img,xvda1,w' ]
vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]
vcpus=1
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = 'destroy'
```

At any time I have errors about installation program don't see `/dev/xvda1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The current CentOS 5 version is 5.9 I would strongly advise to use it
2. Try using xvda - xvda1 is the first partition of xvda - some OS do not like that